# MVC - Add to model based on HTML attrib

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

I'm creating custom forms where the order of the questions/items can be rearranged on the fly. Doing so will update a attribute on the item in the html code.

This is what each item looks like before any questions are 'set' to the form.

```
<li class="field item" order="">
  ...more html for item
</li>
```

and here is how it looks once someone drags the item to 'creation area'

```
<li class="field item" order="1">
  ...more html for item
</li>
```

if they were to add another item below that item it would be

```
<li class="field item" order="1">
  ...more html for item
</li>
<li class="field item" order="2">
  ...more html for item
</li>
```

Naturally, if these items were rearranged the `order` attribute would update as well to show the correction order.

My question is how would i set that `order number` to my model?
I'm assuming this will require some javascript which i'm not too amazing at.

Comment: Your model needs a property for `order` which would need to be updated using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need an `Order` property inside the model.

```
int Order { get; set; }
```

Then you can:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Order)
```

In JavaScript, you'll need to find like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('[0].Order');
```

Watch for what gets loaded in the DOM to see how to find your elements in JavaScript.